# create a trigger in oracle which will not allow any insert or update with if condition

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, sqlplus

I have two tables--

```
create table mobile
(
id int,
m_name  varchar(20),
purchase_date datetime
)


insert into mobile values('1','Samsung corby','12-JAN-12');
insert into mobile values('2','Nokia E5','15-MAR-12');
insert into mobile values('3','Sony Talk','10-FEB-12');



create table location
(
id int,
l_name varchar(20)
) 
insert into location values(1,'London');
insert into location values(2,'Washington');
insert into location values(3,'Mexico');
```

I want to create a trigger which will ensure that sony talk mobile which is in mexico can not be purchased on December.That means whenever I try to insert data in mobile table with ID as 3 and purchase_date as December, the trigger should stop it and give appropriate message.

My code for this is --

```
create  or replace  trigger trg1
before insert or update
on mobile
for each row
declare
var1 number(4);  
begin
select id into var1 from location where l_name='Mexico';
    IF (:new.id = var1 and to_char(:new.purchase_date, 'MONTH') = 'DECEMBER') THEN 
        raise_application_error( -20001, 'THIS mobile CAN NOT BE PURCHASED NOW.');
    END IF; 
end;
```

The trigger was created, but when i try to insert this data using this code--

```
insert into mobile values('3','Sony Talk','10-JAN-11');
```

The trigger fires but gives an error --

```
ORA-04098: trigger 'OPS$0924769.TRG1' is invalid and failed re-validation
```

and my if code is also not working properly--

```
    IF (:new.id = var1 and to_char(:new.purchase_date, 'MONTH') = 'DECEMBER') THEN 
        raise_application_error( -20001, 'THIS mobile CAN NOT BE PURCHASED NOW.');
    END IF;
```

its not checking for both id and purchase_date.
I gave purchase_date as JAN , so in this case the trigger should not fire.
I am confused.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Your trigger was created with compilation errors.  If you type `show errors` after creating the trigger, SQL*Plus will display the syntax errors to you.
2. Oracle does not have a `DATETIME` data type.  The data type of the `purchase_date` column in `mobile` would need to be a `DATE`.
3. The trigger you posted compiles and runs without error on my system once I correct the error in defining the `mobile` table
4. When you use `TO_CHAR` with a format mask of `MONTH`, the results will be right-padded with spaces to the length of the longest month (9 characters).  Since `DECEMBER` only has 8 characters, your condition is never going to evaluate to `TRUE`.  You would need to either `TRIM` the output or to use the `fmMONTH` format mask which does not pad the output with spaces.

Something like

```
create  or replace  trigger trg1
before insert or update
on mobile
for each row
declare
var1 number(4);  
begin
select id into var1 from location where l_name='Mexico';
    IF (:new.id = var1 and to_char(:new.purchase_date, 'fmMONTH') = 'DECEMBER') THEN 
        raise_application_error( -20001, 'THIS mobile CAN NOT BE PURCHASED NOW.');
    END IF; 
end;
```

would be more likely what you're looking for.  But that doesn't explain why your trigger is getting compilation errors.